# Why is (x,y) NoneType?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nonetype

I'm having problem with my code (Jupyter). Ordered pattern vacuum cleaner with obstacles. I am loading an array from a file (see picture if needed)

[image]

Then I have a function:

```
 x_lim = 9 
 y_lim = 9
 
 def ordered_move(x,y,gulv):
     if gulv[x,y] == 0:
         if x < 9:
             x +=1
             return (x,y)
         if x == x_lim: 
             y +=1
             return (x,y) 

     if gulv[x, y] > 0:
         x == 0
         y += 1
         return (x,y)
     
     if x == 9 and y == 9:
         x == 6
         y == 3
         x += 1
         return (x,y)
     
     if x == 9 and y == 3:
         x == 7
         y == 4
         x += 1
         return (x,y)
         
     if x == 9 and y == 4:
         x == 6
         y == 5
         x += 1
         return (x,y)
         
     if x == 9 and y == 5:
         x == 7
         y == 6
         x += 1
         return (x,y)
         
     if x == 9 and y == 6:
         x == 6
         y == 7
         x += 1
         return (x,y)
```

and then I use the code in:

```
x = 0
y = 0
time = 0
dust_in_room = 100 
dust_removed = 0
time_passed_vec = []
dust_in_room_vec = range(100)

while dust_in_room > 7: 
    if array_from_file[x,y] == -1:
        dust_in_room -= 1
        array_from_file[x,y] = -2
        time_passed_vec = time_passed_vec + [time]
        dust_removed +=1
        print(time)
    time += 1 
    (x,y)=ordered_move(x,y,array_from_file)
```

I get the Type Error

> "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

in the last line.
As you can tell from the code I am new to python, so maybe you are able to help with a simple explanation. Thank you.

Comment: You don't always return a result from your function.  What if none of the conditions are met?

Comment: If none of your conditions are `True` in your `ordered_move` function, the function will implicitly return `None`. Thats whats happening

Comment: Also, please make sure you're making a correct assignment. `x == 6`, for instance is not an assignment but it seems you wanted to have `x = 6`. It happens on multiple occasions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that none of the `if` conditions is verified.
If a function ends without a `return` statement the result is like if there was a `return None`.